# Problema al generar lista con una comprensión usando ciclos for anidados y condicional if-else

Tags: python

Estoy intentando generar la siguiente lista:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Primero utilizo el siguiente código sin usar comprensiones:

```
matriz = []
for row in range(3):
    if row == 0:
        matriz.append([1,2,3,4])
    else:
        matriz_nueva = []
        for num in matriz[0]:
            matriz_nueva.append(num + matriz[row-1][-1])
        matriz.append(matriz_nueva)
print(matriz)
```

Y luego intento transformarlo en una comprensión de la siguiente forma:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3)]
```

"Funciona" únicamente si ejecuto ambos códigos uno después del otro; es decir, si la variable **matriz** se encuentra inicializada en memoria como una lista de 2 o más listas.
Si intento ejecutar únicamente la comprensión en una nueva instancia de Python, el intérprete me indica el siguiente error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0320f876870b> in <module>
----> 1 matriz = [ [1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3) ]
      2 print (matriz)

<ipython-input-1-0320f876870b> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 matriz = [ [1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3) ]
      2 print (matriz)

<ipython-input-1-0320f876870b> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 matriz = [ [1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3) ]
      2 print (matriz)

NameError: name 'matriz' is not defined
```

Si, en lugar de ejecutar una nueva instancia de Python, intento ejecutar la comprensión limpiando antes la memoria de **matriz** con `matriz.clean()`, el interprete indica el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2ac574993369> in <module>
      1 matriz.clear()
----> 2 matriz = [ [1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3) ]
      3 print (matriz)

<ipython-input-2-2ac574993369> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 matriz.clear()
----> 2 matriz = [ [1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3) ]
      3 print (matriz)

<ipython-input-2-2ac574993369> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 matriz.clear()
----> 2 matriz = [ [1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+matriz[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3) ]
      3 print (matriz)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Tengo entendido que el problema radica en la visibilidad de la variable **matriz** pero no estoy seguro de como funciona. Agradecería mucho un poco de orientación.
**Nota**: cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está claro. Estas definición `matriz` con una expresión que incluye los valores de `matriz`

> **matriz** = [[1,2,3,4] if row == 0 else [num+**matriz**[row-1][-1] for num in [1,2,3,4]] for row in range(3)

No puedes usar un valor sin definir. Sólo te funciona cuando ejecutas el primer código porque ese inicializa `matriz`.

Con compresión de listas es así:

```
[[i for i in range(n, n + 4)] for n in range(1, 10, 4)]
```

Por partes:

```
[i for i in range(1, 5)]
```

produce

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Entonces esa expresión me sirve para generar una lista cualquiera de cuatro enteros consecutivos si la arreglo un poco:

```
[i for i in range(n, n + 4)]
```

Ahora reemplace los valores fijos 1 y 5 por un parámetro `n` que da el valor de partida. Esta expresión la pondré dentro de otra comprensión que proporcionara ese valor `n`

```
[[i for i in range(n, n + 4)] for n in range(1, 9, 4)]
```

`range(1, 9, 4)` produce [1, 5, 9], que son los valores de partida para cada sublista.

produce

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Creo que me estaba complicando demasiado. ¡Muchas gracias!